# AS2 (not AS3) button that triggers jquery click()

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, externalinterface

I'm really struggling with this. I have a flash demo built in AS2 (not AS3). I want to click on a button and execute a jQUERY click() event to hide/show a DIV that will be shown as "modal" on top of FLASH file.

But I cannot even get an ALERT box to work...

Actionscript

on(press) {
   import flash.external.*;
   ExternalInterface.call('function(){ alert("test"); }');
   }

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I fixed the issue myself. To make it work you have to make sure that access to script is ALWAYS allowed. The following line is inside the  tag of the FLASH:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```